# PHP: using class name as variable name

Tags: php

I have a function as:

```
public function controller_instance($controller_name)
{
      $controller = Router::getRequestedController();
      return $controller instanceof $controller_name;

}
```

and I call the function as `controller_instance('IndexController')`.

This is always returning false because variable `$controller_name` contains string `IndexController`.

How can I make this work?

Comment: What does `Router::getRequestedController()` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make new class from that controller string

```
return $controller instanceof (new $controller_name());
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting a instance or boolean?

Make a array property in the same class where contains the method *controller_instance* and store all instances

```
private $controllers = array();

public function controller_instance($controller_name)
{
    if (isset($this->controllers[$controller_name])) {
        return $this->controllers[$controller_name];
    }
    return $this->controllers[$controller_name] = new $controller_name();
}
```

---

Exemple 2: using ReflectionClass and arguments

```
private $controllers = array();

public function controller_instance($controller_name, Array $args = array())
{
    if (isset($this->controllers[$controller_name])) {
        return $this->controllers[$controller_name];
    }

    $class = new ReflectionClass($controller_name);

    $instance = $class->newInstanceArgs($args);

    return $this->controllers[$controller_name] = $instance;
}
```